# Trouble in launching Unreal Editor 4 built on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have installed Unreal Engine 4 on Ubuntu 20.04, following the instructions from here:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Linux/BeginnerLinuxDeveloper/SettingUpAnUnrealWorkflow/index.html

The compilation and make went fine, but when launching the UE4Editor it crashes with the following error:

```
Fatal error: [File:/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp] [Line: 803] VulkanRHI::vkQueueSubmit(Queue, 1, &SubmitInfo, Fence->GetHandle()) failed, VkResult=-4 at /opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanQueue.cpp:71 with error VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST 0x00007fb25e26e1df libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!VulkanRHI::VerifyVulkanResult(VkResult, char const*, char const*, unsigned int) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp:802] 0x00007fb25e245518 libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanQueue::Submit(FVulkanCmdBuffer*, unsigned int, VkSemaphore_T**) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanQueue.cpp:71] 0x00007fb25e1ddbfa libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanCommandBufferManager::SubmitUploadCmdBuffer(unsigned int, VkSemaphore_T**) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanCommandBuffer.cpp:547] 0x00007fb25e2a6471 libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanSurface::InternalLockWrite(FVulkanCommandListContext&, FVulkanSurface*, VkImageSubresourceRange const&, VkBufferImageCopy const&, VulkanRHI::FStagingBuffer*) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanTexture.cpp:170] 0x00007fb25e2af4d7 libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!FRHICommand<FRHICommandLockWriteTexture, FUnnamedRhiCommand>::ExecuteAndDestruct(FRHICommandListBase&, FRHICommandListDebugContext&) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/RHI/Public/RHICommandList.h:763] 0x00007fb30abdb65e libUE4Editor-RHI.so!FRHICommandListExecutor::ExecuteInner_DoExecute(FRHICommandListBase&) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/RHI/Private/RHICommandList.cpp:373] 0x00007fb30ac5b1c6 libUE4Editor-RHI.so!FExecuteRHIThreadTask::DoTask(ENamedThreads::Type, TRefCountPtr<FGraphEvent> const&) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/RHI/Private/RHICommandList.cpp:428] 0x00007fb30ac5a832 libUE4Editor-RHI.so!TGraphTask<FExecuteRHIThreadTask>::ExecuteTask(TArray<FBaseGraphTask*, TSizedDefaultAllocator<32> >&, ENamedThreads::Type) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Async/TaskGraphInterfaces.h:886] 0x00007fb31042863c libUE4Editor-Core.so!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksNamedThread(int, bool) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/Async/TaskGraph.cpp:709] 0x00007fb310426d3e libUE4Editor-Core.so!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksUntilQuit(int) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/Async/TaskGraph.cpp:600] 0x00007fb30ae17f4d libUE4Editor-RenderCore.so!FRHIThread::Run() [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/RenderCore/Private/RenderingThread.cpp:319] 0x00007fb3104d84e7 libUE4Editor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::Run() [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.cpp:25] 0x00007fb31049c8b3 libUE4Editor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::_ThreadProc(void*) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.h:185] 0x00007fb310e1e609 libpthread.so.0!UnknownFunction(0x9608) 0x00007fb3077e5293 libc.so.6!clone(+0x42)

libUE4Editor-Core.so!FGenericPlatformMisc::RaiseException(unsigned int) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/GenericPlatform/GenericPlatformMisc.cpp:472]
libUE4Editor-Core.so!FOutputDevice::LogfImpl(char16_t const*, ...) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/Misc/OutputDevice.cpp:61]
libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!VulkanRHI::VerifyVulkanResult(VkResult, char const*, char const*, unsigned int) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanUtil.cpp:802]
libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanQueue::Submit(FVulkanCmdBuffer*, unsigned int, VkSemaphore_T**) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanQueue.cpp:71]
libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanCommandBufferManager::SubmitUploadCmdBuffer(unsigned int, VkSemaphore_T**) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanCommandBuffer.cpp:547]
libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!FVulkanSurface::InternalLockWrite(FVulkanCommandListContext&, FVulkanSurface*, VkImageSubresourceRange const&, VkBufferImageCopy const&, VulkanRHI::FStagingBuffer*) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/VulkanRHI/Private/VulkanTexture.cpp:170]
libUE4Editor-VulkanRHI.so!FRHICommand<FRHICommandLockWriteTexture, FUnnamedRhiCommand>::ExecuteAndDestruct(FRHICommandListBase&, FRHICommandListDebugContext&) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/RHI/Public/RHICommandList.h:763]
libUE4Editor-RHI.so!FRHICommandListExecutor::ExecuteInner_DoExecute(FRHICommandListBase&) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/RHI/Private/RHICommandList.cpp:373]
libUE4Editor-RHI.so!FExecuteRHIThreadTask::DoTask(ENamedThreads::Type, TRefCountPtr<FGraphEvent> const&) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/RHI/Private/RHICommandList.cpp:428]
libUE4Editor-RHI.so!TGraphTask<FExecuteRHIThreadTask>::ExecuteTask(TArray<FBaseGraphTask*, TSizedDefaultAllocator<32> >&, ENamedThreads::Type) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Public/Async/TaskGraphInterfaces.h:886]
libUE4Editor-Core.so!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksNamedThread(int, bool) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/Async/TaskGraph.cpp:709]
libUE4Editor-Core.so!FNamedTaskThread::ProcessTasksUntilQuit(int) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/Async/TaskGraph.cpp:600]
libUE4Editor-RenderCore.so!FRHIThread::Run() [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/RenderCore/Private/RenderingThread.cpp:319]
libUE4Editor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::Run() [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.cpp:25]
libUE4Editor-Core.so!FRunnableThreadPThread::_ThreadProc(void*) [/opt/unreal/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/HAL/PThreadRunnableThread.h:185]
libpthread.so.0!UnknownFunction(0x9608)
libc.so.6!clone(+0x42)
```

Vulkan seems correctly installed, as I am using the nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, the reason for the crash was that I enabled Raytracing with my GTX 1060 for the project, which understandably does not work. So, if you have no nVidia RTX card, do not enable raytracing